# Sequence of tenses question

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

What is the right tense of highlighted words in the sentence below? I feel that I'm writing it wrong.

Perhaps you've been contacted before by a customer who **screams** that his site **isn't** working only to find out later that the problem **was** with his connection.

Comment: Another problem with your sentence is that the identity of the person who has discovered the cause of the site malfunction is unclear: is it the customer, or is it the techie?

Comment: Add the words "for you" after "only," to get back on the straight and narrow. Don

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the tenses don't really correspond, but you need to start with a setting in the past, but then want to switch to the present tense for dramatic effect. I can't do better than a majorish overhaul, which separates tenses into two sentences:

> Perhaps you've been contacted before by this well-known customer. He screams that
>   his site isn't working, then after a lot of spleen-venting finally discovers that the 
>   problem is actually his connection.